# Error on make caffe

Tags: compiling, make, caffe

I'm trying to use caffe in ubuntu 16.04. I'm using a virtual machine and I don't have any Nvidia graphic hardware. I'm stuck from this error for 2 days.. Please help me!

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imdecode(cv::_InputArray const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:625: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imdecode(cv::_InputArray const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:625: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin] Error 1
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I found a solution-using cmake. I'll keep in mind the way to ask answers that you commented.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)